# MS Teams: how should we tell if an activity event comes from a bot?

Tags: botframework

we have a chat bot that seems to be receiving messages from another bot. we'd like to ignore these messages, as responding to them leads to an infinite loop of ping pong between the two bots.

we were hoping to rely on `activity.from.role` as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#channelaccount-object), but it seems like [that field is never set](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/blob/master/specs/botframework-activity/botframework-activity.md#channel-account-role).

`activity.from.id` looks something like `28:app:00000000-dfae-4fe1-a068-80fe8fc61f2b_62b732f7-fc71-40bc-b27d-35efcb000000`, and we are thinking that the only way to identify the account as a bot is by detecting the `:app:` in these IDs. this is sub-optimal, as this ID format is not part of the official API and could change at any time.

that said, how should we detect if an activity event is coming from a bot?

Comment: What the underlying framework for your chatbot ? C# or Node.js ?

Comment: Is this a bot from outside your tenant interacting with your bot unitentionally? Or this parent-skill bot scenario where you need to not send responses back to the parent? Can you clarify a bit about your use case?

Answer (score 0):

If you've to deal with potential bots from outside your organisation, a simple way could be to keep a dictionary of few last text exchanges indexed by userId or UserName in the `Activity` object. Then, at each POST received by your bot, check if the received text match fully one of the precedent message entries in this dictionary. If it is the case, then mark the related userId/UserName *as a candidate* for the bot role but continue to check further text exchanges in case a *non bot* user just said hi twice.

If the few following further exchanges doesn't meet anymore the full match requirement, unmark the userId/UserName as a potential bot. If there is marked UserId/UserName as candidate for bot role, apply the bot role to them if there's no more further exchanges past the full match entry or after a delay of your choice. For the latter, it might be useful to provoke a last text exchange after the delay to decide.

For the Watson/Eliza kind of bots, i recommended to check the speed of the exchanges, as far as i know, no human being can exchange more than twenty messages per second.